# Dart Analyzer could not be started on Visual Studio Code

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I recently updated Dart to the latest version but Visual Studio Code still notifies me that 'The Dart Analyzer could not be started'. How do I fix this?

PS, I only have Dart installed. Not Flutter yet because I'm focusing on the language for now. Do I need to install Flutter too to remove this error message?

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnUlX.png)

[Screenshot of error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUdLz.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just restart the dart analyzer it will do, it crashes sometimes